# Find the value of curvature of a curve where α is maximum

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Consider the regular curve α(t) = (t, t²-4t-3), t ∈ R. For what value of t is the curvature of α maximum?

Comment: What have you tried? Please do not just post your homework questions for us to do them with zero effort from you. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You know MathJax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curvature function is $k(t)=\frac{x'y''-x''y'}{((x')^2+(y')^2){\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{2}{(4(t-2)^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

Maimum curvature is $k=2$ at $t=2$ which occured at the vertex of parabola. I didn't know that!

Comment: It is considered bad form to post answers to no-effort questions.

Comment: I liked diff geo question. Sorry.

Comment: If you think about the question at all, it should be obvious that a parabola has maximum curvature at its vertex. :) But, still, you shouldn't be do everyone's homework for them this way.